# Traducción de "assumption" diferente a "supuestos"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, sinónimos, lenguaje-jurídico

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y no me termina de gustar la traducción de "assumptions" por "supuestos".

La frase que quiero traducir es:

> The following are a list of assumptions. Upon agreement and signature of this document, all parties acknowledge that these assumptions are true and correct

El caso es que su traducción al español sería:

> La siguiente es una lista de supuestos. A partir del acuerdo y firma de este documento, todas las partes reconocen que estos supuesto son verdaderos y correctos.

El caso es que no me termina de convencer la palabra *supuestos*.

Las definiciones:

> [Assumption](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assumption): a thing that is accepted as true or as certain to happen, without proof.
>
> [Supuesto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YmdRwDm): Considerado real o verdadero sin la seguridad de que lo sea

A *supuesto* me parece que le falta la parte de "algo aceptado".

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Como @walen creo que supuestos es la traducción perfecta en este caso y además es una palabra muy típica en los contratos, ej.: *...al puesto de trabajo, sólo en los siguientes supuestos: a) ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede decir *premisas* también.  Una premisa es algo que aceptas como fundamento para luego razonar a partir de eso y llegar a otras ideas.

Y sí, estoy de acuerdo con @walen que *supuestos* está bien, pero si quieres una alternativa, se puede hablar de

***cosas que se toman por dado***

En inglés esto viene siendo equivalente de

*things that are [a] **given***

Example:

> Los siguientes siete puntos se toman por dado.  Al firmar etc. todos aceptan estos siete puntos como verdaderos y correctos.

Or

> Al firmar etc. todos aceptan las siguientes premisas por dado.

No sé cuál será el lenguaje acostumbrado de los documentos legales.  (Se puede usar Google para descubrir frases comunmente usadas.)  Pero muchas veces el lenguaje legal es rebuscado y difícil de entender por los que no manejan ese lenguaje especializado.

Comment: Creo que premisa se ajusta más a lo que estoy buscando. Gracias @aparente001

Answer (score 7):

**La traducción está bien. El uso de "supuestos" es correcto.** Las frases *"accepted as true"* y *"considerado verdadero"* significan lo mismo.
Quizá estás viendo en *accept* una connotación relativa a aceptar y firmar el contrato, pero creo que eso es porque vas condicionado por el contexto. El uso de *assumption* no se limita a los contratos.

En cualquier caso, si no te gusta "supuestos", puedes usar sinónimos como "**[suposiciones](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=suposici%C3%B3n)**" o "**[presuposiciones](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=presuposici%C3%B3n)**" (pero nunca Ⓧ"[asunciones](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=asunci%C3%B3n)").